# PHP PCRE (regex) doesn't support UTF-8?

Tags: php, regex, ssh, pcre

I am attempting to run a regex on my site, and I am getting this response:

> Compilation failed: support for \P,
>   \p, and \X has not been compiled at
>   offset 1

After googling for a bit, I've found that apparently my PCRE on my server is not UTF8 enabled, and is therefore causing problems. When I ssh with pcretest -C I get

PCRE version 6.6 06-Feb-2006

> Compiled with   UTF-8 support   No
>   Unicode properties support   Newline
>   character is LF   Internal link size =
>   2   POSIX malloc threshold = 10
>   Default match limit = 10000000
>   Default recursion depth limit =
>   10000000   Match recursion uses stack

When I do yum update pcre it tells me that there isn't anything to update.

People are telling me that I can turn on UTF-8 support...help?

I am a noob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good tutorial on rebuilding the RPM for pcre [here](http://gaarai.com/2009/01/31/unicode-support-on-centos-52-with-php-and-pcre/).

If you scroll down to "Updated RPM file for..." you'll find some pre-built RPM's if you just want it to work (remember to restart Apache after you're done, not just a graceful reload).

The tl;dr version is: recompile pcre with `--enable-utf8` and `--enable-unicode-properties`

Answer (score 3):

Yum should now find `v6.6.6.el5_6.1` of PCRE in its repositories, so performing a `yum update pcre` resolved the issue for me on Centos 5.

Comment: `yum update pcre` worked for me. Don't forget to do a `service httpd restart` after though.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't use the "pcre" application/package.  PCRE support is built in to the PHP libraries.  The error you're getting is telling you that your PHP libraries were not compiled with PCRE UTF-8 support.

You'll need to recompile PHP with the proper PCRE static library built with the proper UTF-8 option.

Comment: okay, that is cool...not to be nuts, but since im really new at this...is there a good newbie tutorial that will show me how to recompile? thanks for your patience...i know its prolly a dumb question

Comment: Honestly I've never had to do it so I really don't know.  Usually it is pretty easy (usually: get the source, untar it, do a configure, then a make, and then a make install).  The tricky part is having all of the pre-requisites.  And you'll possibly need to re-make libpcre.  It is also possible that you *only* need to remake libpcre and not touch php at all.  I'm not sure if php has it statically linked, or dynamically.

Comment: Just to be sure... You meant `pcre` not `prce` right?