# PCRE is compiled without UTF support

Tags: php, apache, freebsd, pcre

everyone! FreeBSD noobie looking for some help with integration of PCRE and Apache with mod_php.

What I have:

- FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE-p3
- Apache/2.2.22 (FreeBSD, built from ports)
- PHP 5.3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr  6 2012 02:58:27) (not from ports)
- PCRE version 8.30 2012-02-04

  ```
  Compiled with
    8-bit support only
    UTF-8 support
    Unicode properties support
    No just-in-time compiler support
    Newline sequence is LF
    \R matches all Unicode newlines
    Internal link size = 2
    POSIX malloc threshold = 10
    Default match limit = 10000000
    Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
    Match recursion uses stack
  ```

`php -i | grep -i pcre` tells me, he uses version of PCRE below:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--with-layout=GNU' 
                      '--localstatedir=/var' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/etc/php' 
                      '--disable-all' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mysqlnd' 
                      '--with-libxml-dir=/usr/local' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr/local/lib' 
                      '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--program-prefix=' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/sbin/apxs' 
                      '--with-regex=php' '--with-zend-vm=CALL' 
                      '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--prefix=/usr/local' 
                      '--mandir=/usr/local/man' '--infodir=/usr/local/info/' 
                      '--build=i386-portbld-freebsd8.2'
pcre
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.30 2012-02-04
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000
```

And everything works fine, when I try to run my php application from command line, in such way `php < somecode.php`.

But when I execute it via apache, I receive this error: `Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0`

I've tried to rebuild apache from ports with `--with-pcre=/usr/local/bin`, but its failed with message that apache couldn't find pcre-config script.

What's could be wrong?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2107027/198536) to a very similar question.

Comment: @wallyk, thanks! But it's not my variant. I've already recompiled PCRE with utf and unicode support and it works fine with php in cli-mode. My problem is in apache pcre-module, if I understood right.

Comment: Did you check that the php on the apache is the same, as the one from the commandline? Maybe you have a second version. Also check, maybe there are two versions of pcre installed.

Comment: Yes, I've just checked. Via pkg_info I found only one `php5-5.3.10_1` and one `pcre-8.30_1`.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding apache module?

Comment: @arrowdodger, yes. Nothing changes(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved problem just rebuilt apache with system pcre instead of default. To do the same, built your apache with `--with-pcre` option, which should contain the full path to `pcre-config` including pcre-config itself. In my case it's `--with-pcre=/usr/local/bin/pcre-config`.

Thanks to all)