# Why does PHP preg_match_all with PCRE_UTF8 give different results on CLI and via Apache/mod_php?

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match-all, pcre

The following code yields different results when run via CLI and via Apache/mod_php:

```
<pre>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)."\n";
// echo setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.UTF-8")."\n";

$terms = array
(
    //Always matches:
    "Label Generation",
    //Doesn't match when using u (PCRE_UTF8) modifier:
    "Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information",

);

$text       = "Some terms to match: ".implode(", ",$terms);
$pattern    = "/(".implode(")|(", $terms).")/is";
$regexps    = array
(
   "Unicode"     => $pattern."u", //Add u (PCRE_UTF8) modifier
   "Non-unicode" => $pattern
);

echo "Text:\n'$text'\n";

foreach($regexps as $type=>$regexp)
{
    $matches    = array();
    $total      = preg_match_all($regexp,$text,$matches);

    echo "\n\n";
    echo "$type regex:\n'$regexp'\n\n";
    echo "Total $type matches: ";
    var_dump($total);
    echo "\n$type matches: ";
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
?>
</pre>
```

CLI output (correct):

```
<pre>
/en_GB.UTF-8/C/C/C/C/C
Text:
'Some terms to match: Label Generation, Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information'


Unicode regex:
'/(Label Generation)|(Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information)/isu'

Total Unicode matches: int(2)

Unicode matches: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Label Generation"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information"
}


Non-unicode regex:
'/(Label Generation)|(Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information)/is'

Total Non-unicode matches: int(2)

Non-unicode matches: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Label Generation"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information"
}
</pre>
```

Apache/mod_php webserver results (incorrect - only matches strings when not using /u modifier):

```
/en_GB.ISO8859-1/C/C/C/C/C
Text:
'Some terms to match: Label Generation, Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information'


Unicode regex:
'/(Label Generation)|(Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information)/isu'

Total Unicode matches: int(1)

Unicode matches: array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Label Generation"
}


Non-unicode regex:
'/(Label Generation)|(Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information)/is'

Total Non-unicode matches: int(2)

Non-unicode matches: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "Label Generation"
  [1]=>
  string(61) "Receipt of Prescription and Validation of Patient Information"
}
```

The web server fails to match both strings when using the /u (PCRE_UTF8) option.
I have tried `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_GB.UTF-8");` to match the web server locale to the CLI locale which it does successfully but it has no bearing on the output.
I suspected an issue with the PCRE library but I don't understand how it can be different between CLI and web server - PHP reports the same library versions in both environments:
PHP 5.4.14
PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.32 2012-11-30

pcretest reports no UTF-8 support but despite this the CLI version yields the correct results

```
$> pcretest -C
PCRE version 8.32 2012-11-30
Compiled with
  8-bit support
  No UTF-8 support
  No Unicode properties support
  No just-in-time compiler support
  Newline sequence is LF
  \R matches all Unicode newlines
  Internal link size = 2
  POSIX malloc threshold = 10
  Default match limit = 10000000
  Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
  Match recursion uses stack
```

Comment: Your question sort of implies that you have checked this but just to double-check - have you compared `phpinfo()`/`php -i` in both envs to ensure that they are both using the same PHP and PCRE versions? Also, what encoding is the test source file encoded with?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yes, both agree on PHP and PCRE versions (5.4.14 and 8.32 2012-11-30 respectively)
Sublime Text reports the file is encoded as UTF-8. Also it is the exact same copy of the file that is used to run via CLI and via web server i.e. only one file.

Comment: There's a possibility that this is the fault of Apache. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037336/pcre-is-compiled-without-utf-support) smells similar, it implies that mod_php is inheriting the Apache PCRE, which sounds a bit funky... :-S

Answer (score 3):

This PHP setting helped me:

```php
pcre.jit=0
```

Comment: This was the solution for me as well when a preg_match worked on the command line but not via mod_php. The PCRE compilation had recently changed to add JIT support and php enables JIT by default if it's available. The CLI version was using a different PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

Alastair, unearthing this ancient question because it deals with a timeless matter of interest of coders throughout the ages.

As Dino said, it's common to have several versions of PCRE on the same box. I'm always amazed at how many versions of PCRE are installed on an average cPanel build. That may not be your situation, but you seem to have multiple versions as well.

To see what PCREs are installed, at the unix shell, type:

```
find / -name libpcre.*
```

If you want to get some meaningful information, you'll want to use pcretest has you have been doing, so you can `find / -name pcretest` then `somepath/pcretest -C`

If you are on cPanel, [according to cPanel staff](http://forums.cpanel.net/f442/pcre-version-compiled-easyapache-used-mod_rewrite-382512.html#post1540211), the version of PCRE installed by EasyApache is the one in the `opt/` folder. You can get the version by running

```
/opt/pcre/bin/pcretest -C
```

It's a mess but that keeps us on our toes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Some Linux distros (Ubuntu for one) package their PHP with separate php.ini files for CLI and Apache. If this is your situation then you may need to poke around in /etc/php5 and investigate the differences.

Comment: Alas, in this situation they are using the same php.ini