# Regular expression Not working in Ubuntu Server

Tags: php, regex, ubuntu

I've been having a small problem in regex in production. I know this is so very simple, but I was annoyed by this issue.

All I need is to allow "ñÑ" string to save in my database.
This is all working in my Local, the problem is when I deployed to production its not working anymore.

```
OS Server: Ubuntu
regex used: "/^[a-zA-ZÑñ0-9\s-]+$/"
```

Did anyone encounter this? Is there any setup or I need to install in the Ubuntu Server? Please help. Thanks.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Update: I added a modifier `u` to my regex:
regex used: "/^[a-zA-ZÑñ0-9\s-]+$/u"

And I get this error:

```
invalid UTF-8 string at offset 11
```

Comment: Use `"/^[a-zA-ZÑñ0-9\s-]+$/u"`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, appreciate your quick answer. I've already done that. I forgot to include in my question that I'm using a Latin1 not UTF-8.
So when I add the modifier "/u" to my regex. 

Message:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 11

Comment: I already did change from Latin to UTF-8. But, I still get the same error. I already checked the char-set in Ubuntu Server and it was using UTF-8.

Comment: Try `\x{XXXXX}` notation, `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9\x{D1}\x{F1}\s-]+$/u"`

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037336/pcre-is-compiled-without-utf-support

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, this works for me "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\x{D1}\x{F1}\s-]+$/u".

What I thought earlier, every time I add the modifier I will always get this error "invalid UTF-8 string at offset 11". But now it's working.. Can you explain what just happen? Thank you very much.

Comment: I changed the close link at the top to the exact dupe now. If you also need explanation, it is [here, by Casimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336400/3832970).

Comment: Thanks you very much..