# How to redirect the WordPress after login

Tags: php, wordpress, pcre

How to redirect the WordPress after login and I am getting one more error just after the installation Some databse error shows that PCRE error.

> PCRE error is : PCRE is compiled without UTF support at offset 0' from
>   regexp

Comment: Seriously ? Can't you post the whole error ?

Comment: [How to resolve PCRE is compiled without UTF support error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037336/pcre-is-compiled-without-utf-support) and [How to redirect after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress) are both duplicates of your question.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect right after successful login, you should hook to `wp_login` like so:

```
function my_success_redirect()
{
    wp_safe_redirect('http://success.com/yay');
} 
add_action('wp_login','my_success_redirect');
```

To redirect after login fail, you should hook to `wp_login_failed` like this:

```
function my_failure_redirect()
{
    wp_safe_redirect('http://nope.com/le-fail');
} 
add_action('wp_login_failed','my_failure_redirect');
```