# Extract words from string with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, string, keyword

I'm not good with regex but i want to use it to extract words from a string.

**The words i need should have minimum 4 characters and the provided string can be utf8.**

Example string:

> Sus azahares presentan gruesos pétalos blancos teñidos de rosa o violáceo en la parte externa, con numerosos estambres (20-40).

Desired output:

```
Array(
    [0] => azahares
    [1] => presentan
    [2] => gruesos
    [3] => pétalos
    [4] => blancos
    [5] => teñidos
    [6] => rosa
    [7] => violáceo
    [8] => parte
    [9] => externa
    [10] => numerosos
    [11] => estambres
)
```

Comment: Explode is not good, i also know how to use str_word_count and make it work with a special charlist but then i have to use a foreach to count characters from each word and i found this an unnecessary step.

Comment: you can use array_filter instead of foreach if that makes you feel better: http://codepad.viper-7.com/AR0AEn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works if the words to look for are UTF-8 (at least 4 chars long, as per specs), consisting of alphabetic characters of ISO-8859-15 (which is fine for Spanish, but also for English, German, French, etc.):

```
$n_words = preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]|\xC3[\x80-\x96\x98-\xB6\xB8-\xBF]|\xC5[\x92\x93\xA0\xA1\xB8\xBD\xBE]){4,}/', $str, $match_arr);
$word_arr = $match_arr[0];
```

Comment: This works. I didn't notice any issues with it and hope i won't find any. Thx @Walter Tross

Answer (score 6):

You can use the regex below for simple strings. It will match any non-whitespace characters with min length = 4.

```
preg_match_all('/(\S{4,})/i', $str, $m);
```

Now `$m[1]` contains the array you want.

***Update:***

As Gordon said, the pattern will also match the '(20-40)'. The unwanted numbers can be removed using this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(\pL{4,})/iu', $str, $m);
```

But I think it only works if PCRE is compiled with UTF-8 support. See [PHP PCRE (regex) doesn't support UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106889/php-pcre-regex-doesnt-support-utf-8). It works on my computer though.

Comment: it will also match "(20-40)" though

Comment: I know i can do the job with regex, is just i don't know how to write the pattern. Your is a good start, still i hope someone improves the pattern.

Comment: @bdsnoobz This pattern is okay, except a single word, all others are okay. I couldn't use the u modifier but it works pretty good without it.

Comment: @flowfree thanks this worked great. What if I want to add to the array also numbers shorter than 4 digits? I would need to get words that are more than 4 characters but numbers which are any number of digits

Comment: @flowfree i'm not sure whether it is correct but i tried doing /(\S{4,}|\d+)/i

Answer (score 3):

that should do the job for you

```
function extractCommonWords($string) {
    $stopWords = array('i','a','about','an','and','are','as','at','be','by','com','de','en','for','from','how','in','is','it','la','of','on','or','that','the','this','to','was','what','when','where','who','will','with','und','the','www');

    $string = preg_replace('/\s\s+/i', '', $string); //echo $string, "<br /><br />"; // replace whitespace
    $string = trim($string); // trim the string
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -_]/', '', $string); // only take alphanumerical characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
    $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

    preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]|\xC3[\x80-\x96\x98-\xB6\xB8-\xBF]|\xC5[\x92\x93\xA0\xA1\xB8\xBD\xBE]){4,}/', $string, $matchWords);
    $matchWords = $matchWords[0];

    foreach($matchWords as $key => $item) {
        if($item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stopWords) || strlen($item) <= 3) {
            unset($matchWords[$key]);
        }
    }

    $wordCountArr = array();
    if(is_array($matchWords)) {
        foreach($matchWords as $key => $val) {
            $val = strtolower($val);
            if(isset($wordCountArr[$val])) {
                $wordCountArr[$val]++;
            } else {
                $wordCountArr[$val] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    arsort($wordCountArr);
    $wordCountArr = array_slice($wordCountArr, 0, 10);
    return $wordCountArr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `u` modifier, you can use the following pattern ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cvUTP9)):

```
preg_match_all('(\w{4,})u', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The [`u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) means:

> u (PCRE_UTF8): This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.

Comment: I couldn't get any good result with this solution, but is true that i cannot use the u modifier. Thx anyway

Answer (score 1):

Explode your string with spaces (which will create an array with all words), then check if the word is bigger than 4 letters.

```
//The string you want to explode
$string = "Sus azahares presentan gruesos pétalos blancos teñidos de rosa o violáceo en la parte externa, con numerosos estambres."
//explode your $string, which will create an array which we will call $words
$words = explode(' ', $string);

//for each $word in $words
foreach($words as $word)
{
    //check if $word length if larger then 4
    if(strlen($word) > 4)
    {
        //echo the $word
        echo $word;
    }
}
```

[strlen();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

> strlen — Get string length

[explode();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

> explode — Split a string by string

Comment: Explode by space it's not good. Furthermore i'm trying to avoid an additional foreach to count characters from each word.

Comment: If it's the comma and dots you are worrying about just do a str_replace to get rid of them. And you don't need an additional foreach loop to count the length of the words. Just say echo strlen($word); in the current foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = Sus azahares presentan gruesos pétalos blancos teñidos de rosa o violáceo en la parte externa, con numerosos estambres

$words = explode(' ', $string);
echo $words[0];
echo $words[1];
```

and so on

Comment: This solution is not good. Some words aren't follow by space, sometime they have a comma or ? or !.

Comment: store your string in an array and take each word one by one if it has a comma trip it and then save the word it its length is 4 or more than that.. I am in class othewise i would try it with myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$str='Sus azahares presentan gruesos pétalos blancos teñidos de rosa o violáceo en la parte externa, con numerosos estambres (20-40).';
preg_match_all('/([^0-9\s]){4,}/i', $str, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: oops, missing a comma sign '/([^0-9\s,]){4,}/i'  caret inside character class [^] is used to negate the result. just tested and output should be like the desired result

Comment: Sorry this isn't getting the results i expect.