# Splitting a string to put into a CodeIgniter Active Record SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to do a search query to see if a textarea contains some keywords. I'm having a bit of trouble though plugging my textarea's values into the query.

This is my query:

```
$match = $this->input->post('wStory');
$this->db->where("`terms` LIKE '%$match%'");
$query = $this->db->get('filter_tbl');
return $query->num_rows();
```

The `$match` is my text field and what I have been trying to do is split up the words inside and then run through each individual word. I have tried using PHPs' `explode()` function which sort of works, but in this case it doesn't work because it turns the string into an array.

Is there any way I can split up the strings in my textarea to just words and run through the words in the like statement, Or is there just something I'm missing?

Comment: does terms contain only a single word per entry?

Comment: Maybe instead of using the sql-where functions, fulltext-search might be more usefull

Comment: @Trent no, it has multiple. I have a fulltext on it and if you put one or two words where the match is it works.

Comment: @Martijn I do have fulltext on the column I'm searching

Comment: Couldn't you just use preg_match_all()? Check at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684183/extract-words-from-string-with-preg-match-all. And after that do an implode(",",$textareaArea)...?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld against what's in the database?

Comment: @zazvorniki - preg_match_all on your textarea.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld  I don't think I understand? Why would I do at preg_match_all and how would I incorporate that with my full text search?

Comment: @zazvorniki - I'm giving an answer now... I hope I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you're currently running is doing a check for a specific phrase, rather than checking for any of the specified words.

You need to do the following:

```
$match = $this->input->post('wStory');

// break search phrase into keywords
$keywords = explode(' ', $match);

// Build query
foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
{
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $this->db->or_where("`terms` LIKE '%$keyword%'");
}
$query = $this->db->get('filter_tbl');
return $query->num_rows();
```

The `explode(' ', $match)` does not take into account any punctuation that might separate words.

Comment: Would there be any reason that this would add extra space around each word? For some reason it seems to be adding extraneous space around each word.

Comment: as well this does not seem to work unless all the words in the query are keywords. If one happens to be not equal a keyword then it returns with a 0

Comment: I've edited my answer to address both issues. I'm not sure how there would be extra spaces, but `trim()` should fix the issue.

Comment: Instead of using `->where()` it now uses `->or_where()` so not all search words are required for an item to be returned. You would need to implement some sort of ranking system so items that contain more keywords will be shown towards the top of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a `$this->db->like("terms", $match);` method?

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#like

Comment: yes, I was trying different things and originally I had a more complex where. I just didn't change it yet in case I added more fields.

Comment: yes, but this isn't really my issue. I'm having trouble with the text field I'm searching being more than one or two words and splitting them up.

Answer (score 0):

I think fulltext search is the way to go. The url Rob W posted also gives this:

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

which in you care would be something like

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (terms) AGAINST ("$match")', NULL, FALSE);
```

Edit: After reading some further, this might be better (or atleast better readable):

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (terms) AGAINST ("$match")');
```

Comment: I'm not really having an issue with the query though, I'm having an issue with the data I'm trying to put into the query.

Comment: I dont know if you are familiar with fulltextsearch, but if you prepare the string $match correctly, it should not be very difficult?

    $matches4query = $match." > ".str_replace(" ", ", ", $match);

small example :)

Comment: I'm using fulltext searches else where I on my site, so I've been working with them for a while. Those though the user posts one of two words. This one though I'm trying to search through a whole text area for a few key words and can't just put the whole text area in the query. That's where my issue is. Thank you for your help! I'm not really understanding why to place the str_replace...that seems to gum up the search.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$match = $this->input->post('wStory');

//Getting words from textarea and put them into array
$wordsArray = explode(' ',$match);

if (!empty($wordsArray)) {
    //use where_in() instead of where()
    $this->db->where_in("`terms`", $wordsArray);

    $query = $this->db->get('filter_tbl');
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error for this. Is the $wordsArray supposed to be $n_words?

Comment: @zazvorniki - no, what are the output of $wordsArray then? ($n_words are only for getting a return-value of the preg)

Comment: @zazvorniki - sorry for that. Try again. Maybe you're getting what you want now.

Comment: $wordsArray is not returning anything. That seems to be causing the 500. That's why I was asking as it seems your not setting anything to that value.

Comment: @zazvorniki - what words do you have in your textarea when you're trying? (what's the value of $match)

Comment: it can be anything the user type in. at the moment it's 'this that and things'

Comment: @zazvorniki - if you do a simple explode() then? Look at updated answer.

Comment: I just plugged the output of this query in my phpmyadmin and it doesn't seem to be running quite right. Even if the keyword is indeed in the string it's coming back false. This was the query codeigniter was outputting SELECT * FROM (`filter_tbl`) WHERE `terms` IN ('this')

Comment: @zazvorniki - if you try to hardcode value $match = 'hello you fool'; What query do you get then?

Comment: I get back SELECT * FROM (`filter_tbl`) WHERE `terms` IN ('hello', 'you', 'fool'), but if I replace one of those words with the keywords I want to check for it still returns false.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32700/discussion-between-bestprogrammerintheworld-and-zazvorniki)